# DotNet Distinct not working as expected on generic list of complex object

Tags: .net, list, generics

Trying to remove duplicate records but **Distinct()** not working with complex object. Is there a easy solution or do I need to override the ReportItem Equals operator?

I have an implementation of code something like the below. I'm ending up with some duplicates and trying to make my Generic list unique. uniqueData is same count as reportData .

```
public class ReportItem
{
    public Guid PRID { get; set; }

    public bool IsDomestic { get; set; }

    public bool IsGlobal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public short SegmentNumber { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string PropertyNumber { get; set; }

    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    
    . . . .
}

List<ReportItem> reportData = new List<ReportItem>();
List<ReportItem> uniqueData = new List<ReportItem>();
foreach (ReportDateRange reportDataRange in getReportDateRangeList(reportParameters, reportConfig))
{
    List<PretripReportItem> result = await _passenger.GetReportData(client, userId);
    if (result != null && result.Any())
        reportData.AddRange(result);
}

uniqueData = reportData.Distinct().ToList();
```